# if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { not working but if (isset($_POST)) { works

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I wondered if anyone can check why my isset submit is bad. If I use (isset($_POST)) { it works but of course it insert too many record to the db because there is many posts on the form. I tried adding any other post name it also would not work. Thank you for reading my question and your help.

-It's not the sql connection, I removed that data on purpose.

Best,

Erik

edit - updated withvardump: array ( 'firstname' => 'dsads', 'lastname' => 'dsadsadsa', 'datefrom' => '', 'dateto' => '', 'dateofbirth' => '', 'email' => '', 'weightkg' => '', 'redacted' => '0', 'heightcm' => '', 'redacted' => '0', 'redacted' => '0', 'mainperson' => '', 'rentalgroupname' => 'redacted', 'submit' => 'submit', 'reservationid' => '1486744492', )

```
<?php
$reservationid = time();


$mysqli = new mysqli("","","","") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO rxids (reservationid) VALUES('$reservationid')");

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>

<form action="resvprocessor.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name"></input><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname"></input><br/>
<input type="date" name="datefrom" placeholder="datefrom"></input><br/>
<input type="date" name="dateto" placeholder="dateto"></input><br/>
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" placeholder="dateofbirth"></input<br/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"></input><br/>
<input type="text" name="weightkg" placeholder="weightkg"></input><br/>
<select name="redacted">
<option value="0">10-13kg</option>
<option value="1">14-17kg</option>
<option value="2">18-21kg</option>
<option value="3">22-25kg</option>  
<option value="4">26-30kg</option>
<option value="5">31-35kg</option>
<option value="6">36-41kg</option>
<option value="7">42-48kg</option>
<option value="8">49-57kg</option>
<option value="9">58-66kg</option>
<option value="10">67-78kg</option>
<option value="11">79-94kg</option>
<option value="12">more than 95kg</option></select><br/>
<input type="text" name="heightcm" placeholder="heightcm"></input><br/>
<select name="redacted">
<option value="0">less than 148cm</option>
<option value="1">149-157cm</option>
<option value="2">167-178cm</option>
<option value="3">179-194cm</option>  
<option value="4">more than 195cm</option>
</select><br/>
<select name="redacted">
<option value="0">beginner</option>
<option value="1">advanced</option>
<option value="2">expert</option></select><br/>
<input type="text" name="mainperson" placeholder="mainperson"></input><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="rentalgroupname" value="redacted"></input>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reservationid" value='<?php echo $reservationid ?>'</input>
</form>
```

Comment: pls post your output

Comment: change `submit` in name to something else like `addIt` and then change the isset to `addIt` also.

Comment: thanks for the input guys, i tried both of those things already - here is a vardump: array ( 'firstname' => 'dsads', 'lastname' => 'dsadsadsa', 'datefrom' => '', 'dateto' => '', 'dateofbirth' => '', 'email' => '', 'weightkg' => '', 'redacted' => '0', 'heightcm' => '', 'redacted' => '0', 'redacted' => '0', 'mainperson' => '', 'rentalgroupname' => 'redacted', 'submit' => 'submit', 'reservationid' => '1486744492', )

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
if (!empty($_POST('submit')) {
//do something if the value is not empty
}
```

Comment: George, this actually fixed it. Could you let me know why? - well, this in combination with changing the name of submit to addIt did.

Comment: actually, this worked for one post, the problem persists

Comment: Hmm don't know then. I had this problem before and used !empty instead of isset and it worked for me